# Why do I have no cold water in bathtubs or washing machine after city water shut off?

Tags: plumbing

The city water company accidentally shut our water off for a few hours. Since then my bathroom tub faucets are not getting any cold water but the sinks work fine. Also the washing machine downstairs is not getting any cold water just hot. I replaced the valve but still the same.

What can I do to trouble shoot this problem?

Comment: Are the problem taps blocked and not letting any water out or water coming out but not the right temperature?